# Creating PATH to Desktop in Ubuntu Terminal in Windows

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-terminal

So, I recently changed to windows. I have been trying to create a PATH to the Desktop so I can easily access it from a command line, since I have to keep entering too many folders every time to enter in the Desktop, I want to type a simple command to access it quick.
In this case I was trying to set this command:

```
cd $Desktop
```

But I get the following error:

```
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

What I attempted to do, In my ~$ path I entered the command:

```
vim ~./bashrc
```

Went to the end of the code and typed the following commands:

```
export Desktop=/mnt/c/User/Nilton\ Schumacher\ F/Desktop
export PATH=$PATH:$Desktop
```

Then I went back to the Ubuntu Terminal and typed:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Use `"` around `$Desktop`. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766).

Comment: It worked, but how can I fix this inside the ~/.bashrc, should I insert $PATH:"$Desktop"?